# Validating slugs in Firebase security rules

Tags: regex, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-realtime-database

I'd like to validate whether inserted slugs are what they should be and have the following function in Bolt:

```
slugify(s) = s.toLowerCase().replace(/[^\w ]+/g,'').replace(/ +/g,'-')
```

used like:

```
validate() = $slug == slugify($this.title)
```

However, the g regex modifier doesn't seem to be supported. Are there any other ways / best practices to achieve my goal?

Comment: It seems that `replace()` here does not allow regex at all.

Comment: Yes, also noticed that  :(  For now, I just dropped the slug validation, but would really like to solve this somehow...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About the best you can do with the allowed string operators is to ensure that your string *looks* like a slug.

```
type Slug extends String {
  validate() = this.test(/^([a-z0-9]+-)+[a-z0-9]+$/);
}
```

Here are some tests against this pattern:

```
  .write('this-is-a-slug')
  .succeeds("Typical slug text.")

  .write('numbers-2016-ok')
  .succeeds("Numbers are ok.")

  .write('double--hyphen')
  .fails("Double hyphen not ok.")

  .write('-leading-hyphen')
  .fails("Leading hyphen not ok.")

  .write('trailing-hyphen-')
  .fails("Trailing hyphen not ok.")

  .write('nohyphen')
  .fails("Must have at least one hyphen.")

  .write('no-Upper')
  .fails("No upper case.")

  .write('no-special&-char')
  .fails("No special characters.")

  .write('no spaces')
  .fails("No spaces allowed.")
```

You can find more [RegExp examples here](https://github.com/firebase/bolt/blob/master/samples/regexp.bolt)